# With .isEmpty() condition, App still crashes

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void grade (View view){
    final EditText varEditBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editBox);
    TextView varText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    if (varEditBox.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EMPTY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        varText.setText( "");
    }

    if ((Integer.parseInt(varEditBox.getText().toString() )>=101)||(Integer.parseInt(varEditBox.getText().toString() )<1) ){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        varText.setText( "");
    } }
```

I have the above code with a condition to check if the EditText box is empty, but any time I press the button with an empty EditBox, the app crashes. I've been debugging but no success. Normally I get this error when I don't do the check, now I've done the check, it's still here. Plus the varEditBox isn't empty, because the other if statement runs as well. If I put in a number more than 100, it toasts "invalid" thus, the second condition works

LogCat error. I'm not sure if I have to post all of it, but this is the error I get

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.listener.gradesystem, PID: 31936
                                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156) 
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                          at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                          at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                          at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                          at com.listener.gradesystem.MainActivity.grade(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156) 
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: `varEditBox` is null for sure

Comment: If you call `toString()` and the `getText()` is empty (i.e. null) what do you think will happen?

Comment: Can you delete the `final` keyword front of the `EditText` and try again ?

Comment: Anytime your application crashes, check logcat and include the stacktrace in your question. A stack trace will help you diagnose the problem. If the stack trace doesn't help you, then it will help us help you.

Comment: @Pavneet_SinghPA it's not empty, cos the other condition works

Comment: @Jon should I edit the question and include the logcat error?

Comment: @staynjokede yes please! Otherwise, people will blindly guess answers. I already see answers that say "try" and "probably" which implies that the authors are making a guess.

Comment: I've updated the code with the LogCat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
```

One of you `Integer.parseInt` calls is failing. I can only assume you somehow have whitespace in your string. If your `EditText` only allows more than just numbers, consider doing this:

```
public void grade (View view){
  final EditText varEditBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editBox);
  TextView varText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  // trim to remove whitespace
  final String text = varEditBox.getText().toString().trim();

  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text) || !TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(text)){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EMPTY OR NOT NUMERIC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    varText.setText("");
    // quit early, don't need to parse this number
    return;
  }

  // we should have already quit by now if we can't parse this number
  int value = Integer.parseInt(text);

  if (value >= 101 || value < 1) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    varText.setText("");
  }
}
```

If this still fails, at least it will highlight where your problem is.

Comment: because your previous code is **if/if** and not **if/elseif**. You're executing both conditions. This code quits before it tries to execute the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this.The problem was in your if else condition.

```
  final EditText varEditBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editBox);
  TextView varText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (varEditBox.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EMPTY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                varText.setText( "");
            }
            else{
            if ((Integer.parseInt(varEditBox.getText().toString())>=101)||(Integer.parseInt(varEditBox.getText().toString() )<1) ){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                varText.setText( "");
            }
        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's not an else if. It's another if statement

Comment: before checking the next if, first you have to check either EditText has some value or not. if your edit text is an empty, the app will crash at next if condition.